# NSWindow width not updated using setFrame(frame, display, animate)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to macos. I am developing an app for macos in which I want user to have side panels and he can hide/unhide as he desires.

I have used `split view` to split my screen into 3 parts. Right and left panels have proportional width to the view (not split view).

What I want is when the user hides the left panel, left pane should hide itself and the left anchor of window should move to right and the right anchor should stay at its position.

Similarly, if user hides right panel, the right panel should be hidden. Right anchor of window should move to left and left anchor should stay at its position.

the following function is called when the user wants to hide/unhide the left panel.

```
guard let window = self.view.window else {
            return
        }
        var frame = window.frame

    if window.isZoomed {
        if leftPane.contentView!.isHidden {
            self.leftPane.isHidden = false
            self.leftPane.contentView?.isHidden = false
        } else {
            self.leftPane.contentView?.isHidden = true
        }
    } else {
        if leftPaneHidden {
            self.leftPane.isHidden = false
            frame = NSRect(x: (frame.origin.x - leftPane.frame.size.width), y: frame.origin.y, width: (frame.size.width + leftPane.frame.size.width), height: frame.size.height)
            leftPaneHidden = false
        } else {
            self.leftPane.isHidden = true
            frame = NSRect(x: (frame.origin.x + leftPane.frame.size.width), y: frame.origin.y, width: (frame.size.width - leftPane.frame.size.width), height: frame.size.height)
            leftPaneHidden = true
        }

        self.view.window?.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
```

I want left panel to be hidden as it works in notability app.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying you want the enclosing window to shrink?

Comment: I want the panel to be hidden. making sure no other panel expands its width. I don't want it to work as xcode works. I want it to work as notablity app works.

Comment: Suppose if the window size is 100. Panel have 15 width each. If one panel is hidden at a time, window width should be 85. If both panels are hidden, window width should be 70.

Comment: See my sample. As is, it should do what you want. (And, if it helps you and you don't mind, check it & up vote it!)

Answer (score 0):

If you did mean that you want the window to shrink/expand, here's a working demo. If you want it to work the way Xcode works, then delete the messing around with the frame. It's implemented programmatically so I don't have to describe the storyboard, but you can easily do the same thing with storyboards. The only code in the left & right views sets the background color so you can see that it works.

SplitViewController:

```
class MainSplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {
    weak var leftItem: NSSplitViewItem?
    weak var rightItem: NSSplitViewItem?

    convenience init(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier) {
        self.init()
        splitView.identifier = identifier
        splitView.wantsLayer = true
        splitView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGray.cgColor
        splitView.dividerStyle = .thin

        let vcL = SubViewController(NSView(), backgroundColor: .red)
        let vcM = MainViewController(MainView(self), backgroundColor: .green)
        let vcR = SubViewController(NSView(), backgroundColor: .blue)

        vcL.view.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        vcM.view.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        vcR.view.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        let sidebarItem = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: vcL)
        sidebarItem.canCollapse = true
        sidebarItem.holdingPriority = NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.defaultLow.rawValue + 1)
        addSplitViewItem(sidebarItem)
        leftItem = sidebarItem

        let mainItem = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: vcM)
        addSplitViewItem(mainItem)

        let inspItem = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: vcR)
        inspItem.canCollapse = true
        inspItem.holdingPriority = NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.defaultLow.rawValue + 1)
        addSplitViewItem(inspItem)
        rightItem = inspItem
    }
}
```

Middle view, with buttons to toggle the side views:

```
class MainView: NSView, DebugHelper {
    weak var splitViewController: MainSplitViewController?

    func labeledButton(_ stringValue: String = "") -> NSButton {
        let button = NSButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0)
        button.bezelStyle = NSButton.BezelStyle.rounded
        button.title = stringValue
        return button
    }
    private func adjustWindowFrame(_ item: NSSplitViewItem, left: Bool) {
        let view = item.viewController.view
        let frame = window!.frame
        if item.isCollapsed {
            let minX = left ? frame.minX - view.frame.width : frame.minX
            let newFrame = NSRect(x: minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width + view.frame.width, height: frame.height)
            window!.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)
        } else {
            let minX = left ? frame.minX + view.frame.width : frame.minX
            let newFrame = NSRect(x: minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width - view.frame.width, height: frame.height)
            window!.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)
        }
        item.isCollapsed = !item.isCollapsed
    }
    @objc func collapseLeft(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let item = splitViewController?.leftItem else { return }
        adjustWindowFrame(item, left: true)
    }
    @objc func collapseRight(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let item = splitViewController?.rightItem else { return }
        adjustWindowFrame(item, left: false)
    }

    convenience init(_ parent: MainSplitViewController) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        splitViewController = parent
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let lButton = labeledButton("Collapse Left")
        addSubview(lButton)
        lButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        lButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
        lButton.action = #selector(collapseLeft)
        lButton.target = self

        let rButton = labeledButton("Collapse Right")
        addSubview(rButton)
        rButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        rButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        rButton.action = #selector(collapseRight)
        rButton.target = self
    }

}
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    convenience init(_ view: NSView, backgroundColor: NSColor = .white) {
        self.init()
        self.view = view
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]